# BuildMI to relative address pointer with the call

Tags: llvm

I try call to the 0x40010 but it looks like LLVM is fixing the adress with his own calculations, is possible to disable it without create inline assembly? My currently code for the task is but the result is not "call 0x40010"

```
    uintptr_t imm = 0x40010;
    const GlobalValue* GV = M->getNamedValue(MF->getName());
    const MachineInstrBuilder& MIB = BuildMI(MBB, &MI, MI.getDebugLoc(), TII->get(X86::CALL64pcrel32));
    MIB.addGlobalAddress(GV, imm, MCSymbolRefExpr::VK_None);
```

Result in MIR

```
    CALL64pcrel32 @test + 262160, implicit $esp, implicit $ssp
```

When i use that code:

```
   const MachineInstrBuilder& MIB = BuildMI(MBB, &MI, MI.getDebugLoc(), TII->get(X86::CALL64pcrel32));
   MIB.addImm(imm);
```

Result is:

```
CALL64pcrel32 262160, implicit $esp, implicit $ssp
```

But when i execute compile i have error: Assertion failed: Target.getSymA() && "Relocation must reference a symbol!"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not doing `call 0x40010`. You are emitting call to the current function plus offset, this is why you're having:

```
    CALL64pcrel32 @test + 262160, implicit $esp, implicit $ssp
```

(`addGlobalAddress` adds reference to the present global value plus offset).

You cannot have a `CALL64pcrel32` instruction emitted with arbitrary immediate address as it is not possible to ensure that the pc-relative offset would fit into a 32-bit immediate field that the normal `call` instruction expects.

The best way would be to materialize the address in some unused register and use call register variant of this instruction (`CALL64r`).

Comment: I'm controll the adress pointers and i see the llvm the same internally check the size of the call, and yes the mov and call it's work but i try avoid - in the default it use rax register but I use rax for other calculations

Comment: Register is an argument. So, you can use any other available register. CALL64pcrel32 encodes a pc-relative offset, so needs a symbol address to emit relocation.